# How to replace string's words first and last characters

Tags: c#, replace, datatable

I have following table structure in my database:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                                     Message                                     |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  { "Body": "lorrem impsum test for @@xxx@@ via @@yyy@@. IsMasa lora @@zzz@@." } |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is how I get the data from the SP

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
parameters[0] = DataAccessManager.GetParameter("@ID", DbType.Int32, id);
DataSet dataset = DataAccessManager.ExecuteStoredProcedure("spGetMessageBody", parameters);
if (dataset != null && dataset.Tables[0] != null && dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    return dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new MessageTemplate()
    {
        TemplateID = row.Field<int>("ID"),
        NotifyEvent = row.Field<string>("MessageBody")
    }).ToList();
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

I need to get the `Message` JSON value from the database and replace it as follows,

```
lorrem impsum test for [xxx] via [yyy]. IsMasa lora [zzz].
```

I need to get JSON `Body` key value and replace `@@` by `[` and `]` . Above method should return this output

```
lorrem impsum test for [xxx] via [yyy]. IsMasa lora [zzz].
```

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, but the problem is when I use as this `value.Replace("@@", "[");` , I'm unable to determine how to use `]`. if @@ in word fisrt I need to replace as `[` if @@ in last in words need to replace with `]`

Comment: Ahh yes good point. You will need to use regex, or count them in and out, or just change the format of the tokens before they are originally saved (which would be the most optimal solution.. then you will have to hope to-all-that-is-good-in-this-world there is no other `@@` in the text

Comment: @TheGeneral Sir,can you please provide me a sample code,please

Comment: Is it always the case that the first set of '@@' in each pair will be preceded by a space character and that the last set of '@@' will be followed by a space character or a '.' character? If so could you replace all occurrences of ' @@' with '[', all occurences of '@@ ' with ']' and all occurrences of '@@.' with '].'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to replace every first occurrence of `@@` with `[`

```
string myText = "lorrem impsum test for @@xxx@@ via @@yyy@@. IsMasa lora @@zzz@@.";

string firstResult = Regex.Replace(myText, "((?:(?!@@).)*)@@((?:(?!@@).)*@@)", "$1[$2");
```

And then replace all the remaining `@@` using `string.Replace`

```
string finalResult = firstResult.Replace("@@", "]");
```

Regex:

`((?:(?!@@).)*)  - first group having a non-capturing group, anything until the first occurrence of @@ 
@@               - first occurrence of @@
((?:(?!@@).)*@@) - second group having the second occurrence of @@`

Comment: Sir when string like `test for [xxx] via [yyy].` this I need this output  `test for ##xxx## via ##yyy##.`  what is the most appropriate way to do it?

Comment: Well, in the code above, have you tried replacing all the `@@` characters with what you want instead?

Comment: yes, which return me error. `string firstResult = Regex.Replace(myText, "((?:(?![).)*)[((?:(?![).)*[)", "$1##$2");`

Comment: Oh, I see.
Now, because the characters you want to replace are different, you could use directly the `string.Replace`. eg. `mytext.Replace("[", "##");`